# Linear Form and Inner Product: Proof

Tags: inner-products

Any source on the proof of this one: Given the field of real or complex numbers, and an inner product on a finite-dimensional vector space over the field mentioned, if $\phi$ is a linear form on the vector space, then there exists a unique v $\in$ V such that $\phi (x)=<v,x>$ for all v $\in$ V.

Comment: No reference, but the name of this result (in the more general, possibly infinite-dimensional setting) is "the Riesz Representation Theorem".

Comment: @StevenTaschuk thanks! Is there an available one for the finite-dimensional case?

Comment: Got this one. Thanks @StevenTaschuk